# ASP.NET MVC - Failed to load resource in Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I noticed if my session expired whilst on my site and then I clicked on an Ajax.ActionLink, the login page would be displayed in a PartialView. I've created an override of the OnActionExecuting method like so:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
    {
        if (!ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (ctx.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                //ctx.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" });
                ctx.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" }));
            }
        }
    }
```

This checks if the User is Authenticated and then if the request is an AjaxRequest. It will then redirect the user to the LogOn method in my Account controller if they're no longer authenticated for an Ajax actionlink. The problem is I get "Failed to load resource" in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This checks if the User is Authenticated and then if the request is an
>   AjaxRequest. It will then redirect the user to the LogOn method in my
>   Account controller if they're no longer authenticated for an Ajax
>   actionlink

Yes, but if you configured your `Ajax.ActionLink` or `Ajax.BeginForm` to update some DOM element with the results of the AJAX request using the `AjaxOptions`, it doesn't really matter if you are redirecting on the server. The AJAX request will simply follow the redirect and insert the resulting HTML you redirected to (/Account/LogOn) inside the DOM element.

So redirecting from an AJAX request won't solve your problem. As you know the whole point of an AJAX request is to stay on the same page (the address bar never changes).

If you wanted to handle the *authentication cookie expired* condition in a proper way within your AJAX requests you will have to perform the redirect on the client (using `window.location.href`). In order to achieve that you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) in which Phil Haack exposes a great technique allowing your server to send a 401 HTTP status code in this case instead of redirecting. Then on the client you could intercept this code (by subscribing to a global AJAX handler for example) and redirect to the logon page from the client.